# Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found after trying out many fixes

Tags: xcode, cordova, jenkins, ionic-framework, xcodebuild

I've been trying out alot of "fixes" but cant seem to get the sudo xcodebuild command to work.

This is the error i get:

[image]

My search header search path settings:

[image]

EDIT: Everything works in xcode itself but fails when i type the xcodebuild command inside my ionic project.